# How to choose correct color space and transfer function with ffplay

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I need to play a video using ffplay that was recorded with GeForce Experience screen recorder, but the rendered video has incorrect colors. It works correctly if I play it with VLC player, but I need it to be played with ffplay only.

Here's the video being played with VLC, which is rendered correctly:
[image: image1]

Here's the codec information:
[image: image2]

and this is how ffplay renders the video:
[image: image3]

Comment: That lools like an HDR to SDR tone mapping problem. Can you add a filter using `-vf "zscale=transfer=linear,tonemap=hable,zscale=transfer=bt709,format=gbrp"` as suggested by a comment at https://superuser.com/questions/1465562/why-does-ffmpegs-tonemap-tone-mapping-filter-give-me-different-colors-dependi

Comment: that worked!! please add that as an answer so I can accept it! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The washed out colours are indicative of an HDR to SDR conversion issue. The `Color transfer function: SMPTE ST2084 (PQ)` indicates an HDR file.

It is possible that VLC is correctly detecting the type of content and the display and doing the correct tone mapping as a result.

You may need to add a filter to do the tonemapping. According to a comment at [Why does ffmpeg's "tonemap" tone mapping filter give me different colors depending on the output format?](https://superuser.com/questions/1465562/why-does-ffmpegs-tonemap-tone-mapping-filter-give-me-different-colors-dependi) a correct filter would be

```
 -vf "zscale=transfer=linear,tonemap=hable,zscale=transfer=bt709,format=gbrp"
```

So your ffplay command would become

```
ffplay -i input.mkv -vf "zscale=transfer=linear,tonemap=hable,zscale=transfer=bt709,format=gbrp"
```